# Is there any EOL( end of life) and EOVS( end of vendor support) dates for spring libs?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-session, eol

Is there any EOL( end of life) and EOVS( end of vendor support) dates for spring libs like spring boot, spring cloud, spring session etc? If yes where can I find these information for each version of libs?

Comment: I don't see why this is off topic. I want to ask the same question regarding the end of life for Spring Boot 1.5.x given Spring Boot 2.0 will be released by the end of the year. spring.io website actually points you to Stack Overflow if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various Spring components move at a different pace. However the Spring Framework (spring core if you will) has rather a long support.
As you can in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/15/spring-framework-3-2-x-eol-on-dec-31-2016) blog post, Spring 4.3.x will be supported until 2019, while Spring 3.2.x went EOL in December 2016 (remember that the initial Spring 3.0.0 release was in 2009).

Spring Boot, Spring Cloud and Spring Session definitely have smaller lifecycles than the Framework so your mileage may vary.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#supported-versions has support dates but could not find for Spring boot